# Fractional Exponents powers

Tags: exponentiation, fractions

I am having problems understanding how to answer questions containing fractional exponents to a given power ie $(2x^{1/2})^6$, i do not understand how to go about answering the question. I know this is an easy topic, but i would really appreciate the help

Comment: (2x^1/2)^6=2x^3. remember (x^y)^z=x^yz

Comment: @jonnytan999: Wrong; Try $(x,y,z) = (-1,6,1/2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule for exponents is $x^{a/b} = \sqrt[b]{x^a}  \forall x \in \mathbb{N}$. For example, $4^{2/3} = \sqrt[3]{4^2} = \sqrt[3]{8}$. You can apply this to your problem to see that $(2x^{1/2})^6 = 64x^3.$

Comment: This is wrong. $(-1)^{6/2} = (-1)^3 = -1 \ne 1 = \sqrt{1} = \sqrt[2]{(-1)^6}$.

Answer (score 1):

> *how to answer questions containing fractional exponents*

In the **exact same** manner in which you answer questions containing **non**-fractional exponents, since the base is obviously a **positive** number, given the fact that both $2$ and $\sqrt x$ are always $\ge0$. $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$ for **all** exponents, fractional or not, it **doesn't** matter. Likewise, $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, again, for **all** exponents. By combining the two, we have $(ab^c)^d=a^db^{cd}$. In this case, $a=2,b=x,c=$ $=\dfrac12$ and $d=6$. And $\dfrac12\cdot6=3$.