# Fractional exponents - how to define?

Tags: functions, definition, exponentiation

Following these threads:
[Thread 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110095/exponent-laws-fractional-exponents-and-negative-bases) and [Thread 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792496/fractional-exponents-powers#), I am still confused about the way we define functions with fractional exponents.

For example, $f(x)=(x^2)^\frac{3}{2}$. Is it true to say that $f(x)=x^3$ when $x\geq0$ and $f(x)=-x^3$ when $x<0$?
In general, should we define $f(x)=(x^k)^\frac{a}{b} = (\sqrt[b]{x^k})^a $ or $f(x)=(x^k)^\frac{a}{b} = (\sqrt[b]{x^{ka}}) $?

Thank you!

Comment: "Is it true to say that $f(x) = x^3$ when $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) = -x^3$ when $x < 0$?" Yes, that is correct.